# How to use CompletableFuture for making two DB call and wait for the result

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Suppose I have a situation where I call two Repositories to get items.

```
CompletableFuture<Optional<Account>> accountCompleteableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->AccountRepository.findById(accountId));

CompletableFuture<Optional<User>> userCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->userRepository.findById(userId));
```

How Can I get a feedback when both are done brining back the results ? Traditionally I would call both one by one and then do the remaining logic. Here I want to speed up the process . I was trying to do something like thenCombine() ,but both are different Objects and I cannot write the logic in inside that lambda. Can any one suggest better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CompletableFuture.allOf( groupCompletableFuture, userCompletableFuture ).join();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you pls tell me the difference between the above and 

accountCompletableFuture.get()
userCompletableFuture.get()

Comment: They are the same but `join` doesn't throw any unchecked exceptions so you don't need a try - catch.

Comment: one more question .. 
So while we create the CompletableFutures , it instantly executes the code right?
even if we dont use the .get() on it right?

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta nothing happens "instantly", it is _scheduled_ for execution, but you should not care about this - since you `join` waiting for the result anyway

Comment: @Eugene So do you mean that It is scheduled for executing and is done automatically. So its not like that only when get() is called then only it start working.

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta right, it is scheduled and starts execution. By the time your code reaches `get`, that `CompletableFuture` might be completed already.

Comment: @Eugene this answer actually solved my doubts , Thanks man !!!!!!

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta you are welcome, [you can read more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605550/why-does-this-completablefuture-work-even-when-i-dont-call-get-or-join/65606195#65606195) for example.